# How to add item to folder item 3 in VBScript?

Tags: arrays, list, vbscript

I want to add an item to items list but I don't know how to do it.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFontSourcePath = "C:\Fonts"
strFontSourcePath1 = "C:\Fonts2"
Set objNameSpace = objShell.Namespace(strFontSourcePath)
Set objNameSpace1 = objShell.Namespace(strFontSourcePath1)
Set objFolder = objNameSpace.Items()
Set list = objNameSpace1.Items()

For Each objFile In objFolder
    If LCase(Right(objFile, 4)) = ".ttf" Or LCase(Right(objFile, 4)) = ".otf" Then
       'add objFile to list?
    End If
Next
```

I try different way but I cant do it. for example I try this

```
list.Add objFile
```

Or this

```
ReDim Preserve list(UBound(list) + 1)
list(UBound(list)) = objFile
```

> for more information : type of list and objFolder  is **folder item 3**

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error message is trying to tell you is that `list` is a collection of the type [`FolderItems3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folderitems3-object). The collection represents the items in a folder, so you can't just add stuff to it. If you want to build a combined list of the items of two or more folders you need to make `list` a regular array and add the items from all folders to it:

```
fontSourcePaths = Array("C:\Fonts", "C:\Fonts2")
ReDim list(-1)  'inintialize empty array

For Each dir In fontSourcePaths
    Set ns = objShell.Namespace(dir)
    For Each f In ns.Items
        If objFSO.FileExists(f.Path) Then
            ReDim Preserve list(UBound(list)+1)
            Set list(UBound(list)) = f
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Adjust the condition for adding items to the array as required.

Note that appending to an array in a loop is an expensive operation that should only be used if the number of items is small. For larger numbers you'll get better performance using something like a dictionary:

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each dir In fontSourcePaths
    Set ns = objShell.Namespace(dir)
    For Each f In ns.Items
        dict(f) = True
    Next
Next

list = dict.Keys
```

or an ArrayList:

```
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each dir In fontSourcePaths
    Set ns = objShell.Namespace(dir)
    For Each f In ns.Items
        list.Add f
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.But I have another question : How can I execute `list.InvokeVerb("install")` at the finally,becuase I can  execute   `objFile.InvokeVerb("install") ` but I can't execute it for an Array ?

Comment: @amir133 You can't call `InvokeVerb` on the list, you need to call it on the individual elements of the list, so you need to loop over them. Also, for that to work you must store the `FolderItem2` objects rather than their paths. See updated answer. For further help please post a new question.